# When using Google's material icons, the page title in the search results has the icon alt text

Tags: seo, search-results, title

i have a problem with my website titles in serp ( over 1000 pages ) 
The title of the pages is in this format

> page title - home_icon Home

I checked my website and I found in the menu link to the home page with home icon using material icons:

```
<a href="/">
   <i class="material-icons right" data-material-icon="home_icon">home_icon</i>
   Home 
</a>
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Your title tag text is either too short or too long. Make it anywhere from 45-65 characters - 50 is generally safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the character using its numeric reference so the word isn't in the HTML. For the home icon, you can use the following.

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to remove the text "home_icon" from your HTML source code:

```
<a href="/">
   <i class="material-icons right" data-material-icon="home_icon"></i>
   Home 
</a>
```

That `<i>` just gets replaced by the icon in the page, so the users don't see the text.   It isn't necessary to have that text there even for screen readers because the duplicate word "Home" would appear right next to it.

Comment: Material icons uses ligatures so the font converts the word "home" into the character. The word is very much needed, that empty tag won't render anything at all!

Comment: I didn't suggest removing "Home", I suggested removing "home_icon".

Comment: Yes, because there's no such icon called ‘home_icon’: it's just called ‘home’, so the word ‘home’ is what's replaced from the string in the tag and ‘_icon’ is ignored. In your code, there's no text in the tag so nothing to replace with the icon.